# How save any apex class code when i write in developer console?

Tags: salesforce, apex

> I am writing apex class in developer console but it cannot save in my
>   salesforce account help me in this regard

Answer (score 1):

There is a Save Option in the File Menu. It is also bound to the keyboard short cut CTRL+S.

Comment: why i cannot see it my apex classes, although i am using ctrl+s

Comment: @RiazMuhammad does your Apex class have any compiler errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you open a new file it asks for class name and automatically saves to your org.

File-->New-->Apex Class

[image: screenshot]

Regards,

Naveen

[autorabit](http://www.autorabit.com)